# Getting error:Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. while working with node

Tags: node.js, express, http, npm, yarnpkg

I am working through setting up a http server using node.js and engine. However, I keep running into issues that I have little information on how to resolve I would appreciate some help solving this please.

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at D:\Coding\pizza\server.js:9:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (D:\Coding\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Below is what I have set up to start up this engine.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path')
const expressLayout = require ('express-ejs-layouts')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.render('home')
})

//set template engine
app.use(expressLayout)
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, '/resources/views'))
app.set('view-engine','ejs')

app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

output of the file should be "Hello from home Page".

Comment: change `app.set('view-engine','ejs')` => `app.set('view engine','ejs')`

Comment: issue has been resolved , Thank you !!